# Image seems to not be centring on Mobile Device

Tags: html, css, mobile-website

I am trying to centre an image on my website - and it looks great when loading the page on a desktop computer, however on the mobile phone browser it appears like this

[image]

The css i am using to centre the image is as follows;

```
#logo
{
    max-width: 60%;
    min-width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto 
}


        <header>
            <img src="images/500x245.png" id="logo"</img>
            <h1>Welcome to AppCloud</h1>
        </header>
```

Can anyone suggest some alternative approaches as my way seems to be failing. Thanks

Comment: add `text-align: center;` to the images parent element and remove the display block and margins

Comment: decrease the min-width it will work perfectly

Comment: indeed it does, how embarrassing! Thanks so much for your help, if you would like to provide an answer i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decrease the `min-width` it will work perfectly

```
#logo{
    max-width: 60%;
    min-width: 300px; /** <<--- changes to be done here **/
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto 
}
```